# Finding rails process server ID debian

Tags: ruby-on-rails, process, webserver, webrick

OK guys,

So i managed to get ruby and rails and all necessary gem installed on out server, (if anyone saw my last question, the firewall was blocking the download of the various packages and gems so they were being currupted) and I started up the rails server, works good, but I called it with -d and now have no idea how to end it..

I've researched, and apparently you have to use the kill command, thats all well and good but I can't find the process ID for the rails server... I'm not even sure what to look for.. in some posts I found before it told me to look in i think usr/lib/tmp, but i dont have a tmp in there..

so, anyone got a better answer for me?

p.s. its a debian server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list all ruby processes by running : `ps aux |grep ruby`.

The second columns contain the process id, you just have to use `kill PROCESS_ID` (replace `PROCESS_ID` by your process number) to terminate the server process.

Comment: apparently ps -ef | grep script/rails also works to find the process. thanks t5hough :D